# Pentaho 7 CE Report Designer Hyperlink BUG

Tags: java, tomcat, hyperlink, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I have been upgrading my reports to pentaho 7 CE, i have came around a weird issue, when using **hyperlinks** on a cell to open sub report, upon **login** to the biserver via the Report Designer Hyperlink window, **SERVER URL** and **PATH** both are auto filled with **BI SERVER URL**, and when selecting the Report to hyper link via the **BROWSER button**, the **parameters** of the drilldown report does not appear on the Report Parameters Tab, this was working fine in the **Pentaho 6 CE Report Designer**, can anyone suggest something use full?

I tried **Pentaho Repository Legacy** option, the Parameters appear fine, but the link is not generated on the report then

upon selecting the report when hyperlinking it gives error:

**org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Expecting // to follow the scheme in URI "http:/localhost:8080/pentaho".**

:( please assist anyone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue so I started to debug the Report Designer and I realize that they created a new class to manage the dialog when you're using the Pentaho hyperlink: `SwingRemoteDrillDownUiProfile`, I commented the line where this class was used and uncommented the other lines inside the file
`org\pentaho\reporting\designer\extensions\pentaho\drilldown\configuration.properties` as follows:

```
#org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.editor.drilldown.profiles.pentaho-sugar=org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.drilldown.swing.SwingRemoteDrillDownUiProfile
org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.editor.drilldown.profiles.pentaho-sugar=org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.drilldown.PentahoSugarDrillDownUiProfile
org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.editor.drilldown.xul-document.pentaho-sugar=res://org/pentaho/reporting/designer/extensions/pentaho/drilldown/sugar-xaction-drilldown.xul
org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.editor.drilldown.xul-controller.pentaho-sugar=org.pentaho.reporting.designer.extensions.pentaho.drilldown.PentahoSugarDrillDownController
```

The `configuration.properties` file can be found inside `report-designer-ext-pentaho-7.0.0.0-25.jar` for `pentaho 7.0` or `ext-pentaho-7.1.0.0-12.jar` for `pentaho-7.1`.

Comment: What about pentaho version 8?

Comment: Well it worked, but when creating new links, it needs ::pentaho-path variable set in the third tab of parameters view, otherwise it will loose state again. Excellent job @Giovanny